# Memory consumption of resource manager

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a resource manager, which is required to be fast and has small memory foot-print. For example, I have an resource class

```
class Abc
{
    string m_name;
    string m_path;
    string handle;
    void SomeFunctions();
}
```

And so on. Now I create and List< Tuple< int,Abc>> and add 5000 items to it. How much memory will it consume? 
One more question: Can I find items base on handle number only, which is the int part of the Tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory consumption is very difficult to estimate without knowing the average string sizes.

If the integer handle is unique per `Abc` instance, you should use a `Dictionary<int, Abc>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)